# Save dynamic user input - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, logic

This is more like a logical question because I'm not finding a correct approach for this query.

I have 2 auditoriums with x amount of seats in the below fashion.

```
<div>
        <pre>

        Auditorium 1:  A1 A2 A3 A4 A A6 A7 A8 A9
                       B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7
                          C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
        </pre>
</div>
<div>
        <pre>

        Auditorium 2:  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7
                          B2 B3 B4 B5 B6
                       C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
        </pre>
</div>
```

I have stored these seat numbers using 2 arrays, one for each auditorium. Now, if the auditorium owner decides to construct one more auditorium in his building, what would be an efficient way of asking the owner for his auditorium 3 seating arrangements dynamically, since they should be displayed in the above same way - seats one below another? and how would I dynamically store the seat numbers in an array at the same time?

```
Auditorium 3 example:
            

                A1 A2 A3 A4 A A6 A7
                B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8
                   C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in the below format.,

```
 let Auditorium3 = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, X, X, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, X, X, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9]
```

which you will show in the below format excluding 'X' in your logic and considering maximum of A1 to A9(fully occupied A row) similarly,  B1 to B9(fully occupied B row), C1 to C9(fully occupied C row)

```
Auditorium 3 :
            
                A1 A2 A3 A4 A A6 A7
                B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8
                   C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: This would possibly work, but when I need to display the seating arrangements in HTML (C2 below B2, B4 below A4 etc.) , it would be cumbersome to write the logic for it. Is there any way, we can directly take the seating arrangement as input?

Comment: @Snk This should work actually. For every X, print an empty space. This should automatically create your seating arrangement.